# How to disable and enable the the overflow Button on different fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar, buffer-overflow

I have and application in which I am using the Single activity and different fragments let say on activity start I call fragment A , and then after taking inputs I switch to fragment B and then Fragment C .

For Some reasons I have changed the Overflow Icon successfully from styles. But now The only problem is that for some reasons I want to show the overflow icons on Fragment B but not on Fragment A and C .  for this I am doing this

```
 public static void setOverflowButtonColor(final Activity activity, final int i) {
        final String overflowDescription = activity.getString(R.string.abc_action_menu_overflow_description);
        final ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = decorView.getViewTreeObserver();
               viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onGlobalLayout() {
                       TintImageView overflow = null;

                       final ArrayList<View> outViews = new ArrayList<View>();
                       decorView.findViewsWithText(outViews, overflowDescription,
                               View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
                       if (outViews.isEmpty()) {
                           return;
                       }
                       overflow = (TintImageView) outViews.get(0);
                       //overflow.setColorFilter(Color.CYAN);
                       overflow.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_overflow_image);
                       if (i == 1 && overflow!=null) {
                           overflow.setEnabled(false);
                           overflow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       } else if (overflow != null) {

                           overflow.setEnabled(true);
                           overflow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }

                       overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               Toast.makeText(activity, "Overflow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       });
                       removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(decorView, this);
                   }
               });
    }
    public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
        }
        else {
            v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
        }
    }
```

So from Fragment A I am sending 1 in parameter so to hide the Icon but from Activity B I am sending 0 in parameter to re visible it , but it is not getting call.

Let me tell you this function working when it is called from  Fragment A , I mean it is calling one time but not 2nd time or so on .

please tell me how to do this , if you know any other best method

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface like below.

```
public interface FragmentHost{
        public void onFragmentChange(int currentFragment);
    }
```

Activity A should implement this interface.

```
class A extends Activity implents FragmentHost {

public static final int FRAGMENT_B = 0;
public static final int FRAGMENT_C = 1;

@Override
public void onFragmentChange(int currentFragment) {

if (currentFragment == FRAGMENT_A) {
// enable or disable button
} else if(currentFragment == FRAGMENT_B) {
// enable or disable button
}
}

}
```

And in each fragment . OnResume function call the onFragmentChange() method and pass the fragment id.

```
class B extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onResume() {
((FragmentHost) getParentActivity()).onFragmentChange(A.FRAGMENT_B);
}

}
```